# MySQL Tracing the ancestor of a hierarchal one to many data structure

Tags: mysql, sql

If you have say 3 tables. A record in table A is related many records in table B. A record in table B is related to many tables in table C.

Now given an id of a row inside table C, how can I trace back the original ancestor row in table A, if I have no knowledge of table B?

The goal is to find out whether a particular row is "owned" by an entity inside table A. The reality is that there could be multiple one to many levels in between table A and table C.

Comment: what do you mean by "if I have no knowledge of table B"?

Comment: Well in a programming environment, let's say I have the a row from table C. I know the id and I know table C's name. But I want to know if a row from table A owns the row in table C. There's no direct junction table relating A to C, but I do know there is a extended chain between table A to B to C. But I don't know table B's name. Is there a data structure more suited to these kind of situations, or a particular path finding query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the 3 choices that I can think about:

1) have a column in table C that holds the table A reference. This involves a bit of denormalization but it effective.

so you would have a schema like this table A (id, ....), table B(id, a_id, ...), table C(id, a_id, b_id, ...)

2) keep track of table B's name in table C: so you will have something like table C(id, parent_object_table, parent_object_id, ...) this will allow you to recover both the parent's table name and row ID

3) if these tables have the same structure (e.g. menu, submenu), it might be better to just have one table instead and have a parent_id column to keep track of the direct parent, and an optional depth column to know how far down the tree the row is

**Edit**

ok, if I understood you correctly you want to build a dynamic tree structure.

try something like this:

Table tree

```
id
object_table
object_id
parent_object_table
parent_object_id
depth
```

So a table_c record with (id: 15, table_b parent: 12, table_a parent: 3) will have 2 records:

```
object_table = 'table_c'
object_id = 15
parent_object_table = 'table_b'
parent_object_id = 12
depth = 1
```

and

```
object_table = 'table_c'
object_id = 15
parent_object_table = 'table_a'
parent_object_id = 3
depth = 2
```

You can also add another record depending on your use case that is going to allow all you records to be present in this table ( and might be more implicit).

```
object_table = 'table_c'
object_id = 15
parent_object_table = 'table_c'
parent_object_id = 15
depth = 0
```

This will allow rows without parents to also be in this table

Comment: I'm trying to acquire a scalable elegant solution. Option 1 and Option 2 both require schema changes when new tables added in between this chain. Is there a single table that can relate all the resources in all the tables? Something like a closure table, but used for for multiple tables.

Comment: is number 3 not an option ?

Comment: Open 3 is not possible, because the tables have to be normalised.

Comment: what about my edit ? BTW, true normalization will require schema updates when a new table is added to the mix since the relationship needs to be normalized.

Comment: Your edit was exactly what I was thinking about. Also you're missing another record, the record between table_b to table_a. I think this is the right way to do it. Will try it out and come back. Still have to figure out the right queries to use.

Comment: yes the record between table b and a is done the same way as the ones I showed. (I only gave the table_c record as an example).

Comment: I've hit a problem. How do we know what the depth is when we are inserting new data?

Comment: that depends on your logic, it is impossible to say without knowing how you go about adding new rows

Comment: Oh I got it. I'll post up extra details soon.

Answer (score 0):

@redmoon007 gave the right answer. But to elaborate, here's how such table is created. Decided to call it the multitable superjunction closure.

```
SET @table_associations = 'pa_associations';

SET @associations_create = CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ',
    @table_associations,
    ' (
        `ancestorName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        `ancestorId` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `descendantName` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
        `descendantId` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        `depth` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`ancestorName`, `ancestorId`, `descendantName`, `descendantId`)
    ) ',
    ' ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
);

PREPARE statement FROM @associations_create;
EXECUTE statement;
```

Here are queries that can utlise this, based off these slides when he gets to closures: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

```
  -- Here's an example query to acquires *all* user ancestors given a permission ID of 1:

      SELECT * FROM pa_accounts AS accounts 
      JOIN pa_associations AS associations 
          ON accounts.id = associations.ancestorId 
      WHERE associations.descendantId = 1 
          AND associations.descendantName = 'pa_permissions' 
          AND associations.ancestorName = 'pa_accounts';

  -- Here's an example query that inserts a relationship between the 4th role and the 10th permission:

      INSERT INTO pa_associations (ancestorName, ancestorId, descendantName, descendantId, depth)
      SELECT 
          ancestorName, 
          ancestorId, 
          'pa_permissions', 
          10,
          depth + 1,
      FROM pa_associations
      WHERE descendantId = 4 AND descendantName = 'pa_roles'
      UNION ALL SELECT 'pa_permissions', 10, 'pa_permissions', 10, 0;
```